# Java 8 stream filter return first condition meet

Tags: java, java-stream

I am wondering how I can get from an array the item that match the first condition

For ex.:
let say that I have a list of string

list={"a","b","c","d","e"}

and a list of condition

cond1= "c"

cond2="e"

cond3="b"

my question is in java stream how I can get the first element of the first condition meet?

something like

```
if(cond1 found)
  return first element 
else if (cond2 found)
  return first element 
else if (cond3 found)
  return first element
```

I try do it with predicate but it seems to return element from an arbitrary condition

```
Predicate<String> pCond1 = i -> i.equalsIgnoreCase("c");
Predicate<String> pCond2 = i -> i.equalsIgnoreCase("e");
Predicate<String> pCond3 = i -> i.equalsIgnoreCase("b");
            
Optional<String> result = list.stream()
            .filter(pCond1.or(pCond2).or(pCond3))
            .findFirst();
```

UPDATE

I forgot to say that list is not ordered

So the list can be like

list={"e","c","a","d","b"}

the result from this example should be "c" since c is first condition that match

another example

list={"e","a","d","b"}

the result should be "e" since condition c failed but the 2nd condition "e" match

Comment: Your description doesn't seem to match your example, which makes your question confusing. Do you really want to find "item that match the *first condition*" (so I am assuming that if there are many conditions only first condition should we care about) OR something more like "*first item* that matches any condition"?

Comment: So could you clarify what results you would expect (include your logic) and what you get instead (and why do you think it is incorrect)?

Comment: As I wrote I want the item that match the first condition. What I didn't wrote and I apologize for that is that the list is not ordered.
I wrote in pseudo code the logic

Comment: Just checking if I understood. You want to first check entire list to search for element matching first condition. If it fails to find any match you want to search for element which may match second condition, and if that fails too you will want to search for element matching third condition. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one could do this:

```java
Optional<String> opt = Stream.of(pCond1, pCond2, pCond3)
    .map(condition -> list.stream()
        .filter(condition)
        .findAny()
        .orElse(null))
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .findFirst();
```

It streams over all conditions, mapping it to a value if it is found, otherwise it filters it out. This makes sure that results from the first condition are always first in the stream, if the condition was satisfied. At last, `findFirst()` makes sure that the match to the first condition is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like this:

```
Optional<String> result = list.stream().filter(s ->s.equals("c") || s.equals("e") || s.equals("b")).findFirst();
```

Comment: This will not work ... maybe I forgot to say that the list is not ordered so if the filter match the 2nd condition first it will return the item

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream.of(i -> i.equalsIgnoreCase("c"), i -> i.equalsIgnoreCase("e"), i -> i.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
   .map(predicate -> list.stream().filter(predicate).findFirst())
   .flatMap(Optional::stream) // or .filter(Optional::isPresent).map(Optional::get) in jdk8
   .findFirst()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
conditionsList={"b","c","e"}

String result = list.stream().filter(conditionsList::contains).findFirst().orElse(null);
```

The result will be null if condition does not meet.